# React conditional rendering is not giving the expected value (it is not working)

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I am trying to disable a button if the array length is > 0 and if the array length is equal to zero it need to show the button (without disable)

I tried conditional rendering for that like this.

```
                   {this.state.aboutus.map((item) => (
                        (this.state.aboutus.length > 0 ?
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} disabled={true}>
                                <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
                            </button>
                            :

                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} onClick={() => { window.location.href = APP_ROUTES.ADMIN_ADD_ABOUT_US }}>
                                <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
                            </button>
                        )
                    ))}
```

In here if the this.state.aboutus.lenght is > 0 I want to disable the button and otherwise it doesn't need to disable. But when I use this code and even if there is no data in the database is is not showing the button. But if there is one data the but is disabled.

I don't know what is wrong in this coding. Please help.

Comment: if `this.state.aboutus.length == 0` then then handler function inside `this.state.aboutus.map` will never be called (because there is no element `this.state.aboutus`), so it's normal you don't see any button when the array is empty

Comment: Oh so how can I implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function,

```
(item) => (
                    (this.state.aboutus.length > 0 ?
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} disabled={true}>
                            <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
                        </button>
                        :

                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} onClick={() => { window.location.href = APP_ROUTES.ADMIN_ADD_ABOUT_US }}>
                            <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
                        </button>
                    )
```

there is no reference to the **item**, so you don't need to use map:

When the array is empty,  map never runs, so your button is never rendered.

To solve the issue, simply omit  map:

```
<div>{
  (this.state.aboutus.length > 0 ?
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} disabled={true}>
          <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
      </button>
      :

      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} onClick={() => { window.location.href = APP_ROUTES.ADMIN_ADD_ABOUT_US }}>
          <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
      </button>
  )
}</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I just realized that I haven't used the item..

Answer (score 0):

Well, You do NOT need to use map for that.

You can just do following.

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-info" style={{ float: 'right', padding: '12px 28px', marginBottom: '30px' }} disabled={this.state.aboutus.length}>
                                <PlusLg /> Add About Us Details
                            </button>
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit or provide a complete code for how I can disable if there is 1 data and not disable if there is no data?

Comment: You don't need map. Just write your buttons how I did in my answer )

Comment: If I did like that, still the button is not showing

Comment: What do you mean not showing? Did you remove the `map` code?

Comment: Yes. I removed the mapping and add only this. But the button didn't show

Comment: If did not work then why you have accepted the answer ?))) Share you complete componet code.